# How long do browsers store Javascript variables in memory?

Tags: javascript

I understand sessionStorage and localStorage can be used to store variables longer term, but how long will a page store a simple `var x = 1` variable?

Scenario:

A user loads a page on his phone. `var x = 1` is set in the background. He closes the browser (minimises the app; doesn't close the page) and doesn't re-open it for a week. Is `x` still equal to `1`?

Comment: They moment the page is gone/closed the variable cease to exist. Assuming this is a global variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So there is no difference between closing and minimising the browser? Or it depends?

Comment: They last as long as they are referencing the `Window` object (recursive up tree). Afterwards it is up to the garbage collector.

Comment: Your scenario is very dependent on the mobile browser used, how it and the OS handle caching, memory etc., and can't possibly be answered in general IMHO. If you _need_ a value to still be present after that week, then use a proper storage mechanism designed for that, don't rely on pure in-memory variables.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, this is unfortunately what I suspected... :(

Answer (score 0):

When the page is closed, then the global variables are deleted. The local variables are deleted after the scope of the local variable ends.

Minimization has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

When the user closes the page, all variables cease to exist. However, if the user never closes the page, the variables will always stay the same, assuming no background `function` is going to change them.

`x` will always be equal to `1` as it is a global variable and no other `function`s change its value:

```
<script>
var x = 1;
</script>
```

As soon as the following function is run, `y` no longer exists and can not be accessed outside of the function because it is a local variable declared inside a function:

```
function doSomething(){
 var y = 1;
}
```

Comment: A local `x` has no effect on a global `x`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I meant this as if global variable `x` did not exist.

Comment: How you phrasing it seems to imply the local variable exist before the function is ran. It's better to say the variable only exist while the function is being executed, once it's execution stops the local variable is gone.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Sorry about the confusion. I have changed the local variable name to `y`.

Answer (score 0):

> He closes the browser (minimises the app; doesn't close the page) and doesn't re-open it for a week. Is x still equal to 1?

That depends. The variable gets lost when the page gets closed, which happens when the browser decides to close / reload it, or when the whole browser gets closed. Wether that happens depends on your devices settings, some possible scenarios:

- apps in background usually get closed when you are runnig out of RAM.
- the phone was restarted
- the appdata was cleared
- the pages meta sets a refresh time, which the browser follows